# Bayesian two-factor ANOVA

Tags: r, bayesian, anova, bugs

I am interested in fitting a Bayesian Two Factor ANOVA in BUGS or by utilizing some R package.  Unfortunately I am having a hard time finding resources on this topic.  Any suggestions?  Even an article describing the approach would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simon Jackman has some working code for fitting ANOVA and regression models with [JAGS](http://www-ice.iarc.fr/~martyn/software/jags/) (which is pretty like BUGS), e.g. [two-way ANOVA via JAGS](http://jackman.stanford.edu/classes/BASS/madrid/madridWednesday.R) (R code) or maybe among his handouts on [bayesian analysis for the social sciences](http://jackman.stanford.edu/classes/BASS/index.php).

A lot of WinBUGS code, including one- and two-way ANOVA, seem to be available on the companion website for [Bayesian Modeling Using WinBUGS: An introduction](http://stat-athens.aueb.gr/~jbn/winbugs_book/).

Answer (score 5):

I'm a bit late to the show here, but John  Kruschke's recently published book `Doing Bayesian Data Analysis: A Tutorial with R and BUGS` has a whole chapter (19) on this. His book is written in a highly accessible and practical style, well worth checking out for his description of the approach. He also includes R and BUGS code for his examples.

His website accompanying the book is interesting reading also: http://www.indiana.edu/~kruschke/DoingBayesianDataAnalysis/ and includes all the code in the book.

Answer (score 4):

See Chapter 10 of Marc Kery's book Introduction to WinBUGS for Ecologists, where he compares a two-way ANOVA in R with several versions of the model in WinBUGS. (The book has lots of great examples; ecology not a pre-requisite.) Website for the book is here: http://www.mbr-pwrc.usgs.gov/software/kerybook/