# How would you do Bayesian ANOVA and regression in R?

Tags: r, regression, bayesian, anova, inference

I have a fairly simple dataset consisting of one independent variable, one dependent variable, and a categorical variable. 
I have plenty of experience running frequentist tests like `aov()` and `lm()`, but I cannot figure out how to perform their bayesian equivalents in R.

I would like to run a bayesian linear regression on the first two variables and a bayesian analysis of variance using the categorical variable as the groupings, but I cannot find any simple examples on how to do this with R. Can someone provide a basic example for both? Additionally, what exactly are the output statistics created by bayesian analysis and what do they express?

I am not very well-versed in stats, but the consensus seems to be that using basic tests with p-values is now thought to be somewhat misguided, and I am trying to keep up.
Regards.

Comment: [Doing Bayesian Data Analysis: A Tutorial with R and BUGS](http://www.indiana.edu/~kruschke/DoingBayesianDataAnalysis/) may be a good start. There are also some links for Bayesian ANOVA on this related question: [Bayesian two-factor ANOVA](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/11437/930). I'm not clear with your last sentence, though, because instead of interpreting p-value we generally recommend using measure of [effect size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size).

Answer (score 12):

If you intend to do a lot of Bayesian statistics you would find it helpful to learn the BUGS/JAGS language, which can be accessed in R via the R2OpenBUGS or R2WinBUGS packages.

However, for the sake of a quick example that doesn't require understanding BUGS syntax, you could use the "bayesm" package which has the runiregGibbs function for sampling from the posterior distribution. Here is an example with data similar to that which you describe.....

```
library(bayesm)

podwt <- structure(list(wt = c(1.76, 1.45, 1.03, 1.53, 2.34, 1.96, 1.79, 1.21, 0.49, 0.85, 1, 1.54, 1.01, 0.75, 2.11, 0.92), treat = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("I", "U"), class = "factor"), mus = c(4.15, 2.76, 1.77, 3.11, 4.65, 3.46, 3.75, 2.04, 1.25, 2.39, 2.54, 3.41, 1.27, 1.26, 3.87, 1.01)), .Names = c("wt", "treat", "mus"), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")

# response
y1 <- podwt$wt

# First run a one-way anova

# Create the design matrix - need to insert a column of 1s
x1 <- cbind(matrix(1,nrow(podwt),1),podwt$treat)

# data for the Bayesian analysis
dt1 <- list(y=y1,X=x1)

# runiregGibbs uses a normal prior for the regression coefficients and 
# an inverse chi-squared prior for va

# mean of the normal prior. We have 2 estimates - 1 intercept 
# and 1 regression coefficient
betabar1 <- c(0,0)

# Pecision matrix for the normal prior. Again we have 2
A1 <- 0.01 * diag(2)
# note this is a very diffuse prior

# degrees of freedom for the inverse chi-square prior
n1 <- 3  

# scale parameter for the inverse chi-square prior
ssq1 <- var(y1) 

Prior1 <- list(betabar=betabar1, A=A1, nu=n1, ssq=ssq1)

# number of iterations of the Gibbs sampler
iter <- 10000  

# thinning/slicing parameter. 1 means we keep all all values
slice <- 1 

MCMC <- list(R=iter, keep=slice)

sim1 <- runiregGibbs(dt1, Prior1, MCMC)

plot(sim1$betadraw)
    plot(sim1$sigmasqdraw)

summary(sim1$betadraw)
    summary(sim1$sigmasqdraw)

# compare with maximum likelihood estimates:
fitpodwt <- lm(wt~treat, data=podwt)
summary(fitpodwt)
anova(fitpodwt)


# now for ordinary linear regression

x2 <- cbind(matrix(1,nrow(podwt),1),podwt$mus)

dt2 <- list(y=y1,X=x2)

sim2 <- runiregGibbs(dt1, Prior1, MCMC)

summary(sim1$betadraw)
    summary(sim1$sigmasqdraw)
plot(sim$betadraw)
    plot(sim$sigmasqdraw)

# compare with maximum likelihood estimates:
summary(lm(podwt$wt~mus,data=podwt))


# now with both variables

x3 <- cbind(matrix(1,nrow(podwt),1),podwt$treat,podwt$mus)

dt3 <- list(y=y1,X=x3)

# now we have an additional estimate so modify the prior accordingly

betabar1 <- c(0,0,0)
A1 <- 0.01 * diag(3)
Prior1 <- list(betabar=betabar1, A=A1, nu=n1, ssq=ssq1)

sim3 <- runiregGibbs(dt3, Prior1, MCMC)

plot(sim3$betadraw)
    plot(sim3$sigmasqdraw)
summary(sim3$betadraw)
    summary(sim3$sigmasqdraw)

# compare with maximum likelihood estimates:
summary(lm(podwt$wt~treat+mus,data=podwt))
```

Extracts from the output are:
**Anova:**
Bayesian:

```
Summary of Posterior Marginal Distributions 
Moments 
   mean std dev num se rel eff sam size
1  2.18    0.40 0.0042    0.99     9000
2 -0.55    0.25 0.0025    0.87     9000

Quantiles 
  2.5%    5%   50%   95%  97.5%
1  1.4  1.51  2.18  2.83  2.976
2 -1.1 -0.97 -0.55 -0.13 -0.041
```

lm():

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   1.6338     0.1651   9.895 1.06e-07 ***
treatU       -0.5500     0.2335  -2.355   0.0336 *
```

**Simple linear regression:**
Bayesian:

```
Summary of Posterior Marginal Distributions 
Moments 
  mean std dev  num se rel eff sam size
1 0.23   0.208 0.00222     1.0     4500
2 0.42   0.072 0.00082     1.2     4500

Quantiles
   2.5%    5%  50%  95% 97.5%
1 -0.18 -0.10 0.23 0.56  0.63
2  0.28  0.31 0.42 0.54  0.56
```

lm():

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.23330    0.14272   1.635    0.124    
mus          0.42181    0.04931   8.554 6.23e-07 ***
```

**2 covariate model:**
Bayesian:

```
Summary of Posterior Marginal Distributions 
Moments 
   mean std dev  num se rel eff sam size
1  0.48   0.437 0.00520     1.3     4500
2 -0.12   0.184 0.00221     1.3     4500
3  0.40   0.083 0.00094     1.2     4500

Quantiles 
   2.5%    5%   50%  95% 97.5%
1 -0.41 -0.24  0.48 1.18  1.35
2 -0.48 -0.42 -0.12 0.18  0.25
3  0.23  0.26  0.40 0.53  0.56
```

lm():

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.36242    0.19794   1.831   0.0901 .  
treatU      -0.11995    0.12688  -0.945   0.3617    
mus          0.39590    0.05658   6.997 9.39e-06 ***
```

from which we can see that the results are broadly comparable, as expected with these simple models and diffuse priors. Of course it is also worth inspecting the MCMC diagnostic plots - posterior density, trace plot, auto correlation - that I also gave the code for above which (plots not shown).

Comment: So I ran the linear regression against two independent variables separately- both of which perform with fairly well (~0.01) p-values using the frequentist lm() test. With the bayesian test, one of these variables produces very similar and significant results for the intercept and the slope, but for the other, which actually has a slightly lower p-value, the bayesian result gives wildly different (and statistically insignificant) values. Any idea what this might mean?

Comment: @Barzov you should post a new question, and include your code and (if possible) your data.

Answer (score 2):

The BayesFactor package (demonstrated here: http://bayesfactorpcl.r-forge.r-project.org/ and available on CRAN) allows Bayesian ANOVA and regression. It uses Bayes factors for model comparison and allows posterior sampling for estimation.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite convenient with the `LearnBayes` package.

```
fit <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data=iris, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)
library(LearnBayes)
posterior_sims <- blinreg(fit$y, fit$x, 50000)
```

The `blinreg` function uses a noninformative prior by default, and this yields an inference very close to the frequentist one.

**Estimates**:

```
> # frequentist 
> fit$coefficients
      (Intercept) Speciesversicolor  Speciesvirginica 
            5.006             0.930             1.582 
> # Bayesian
> colMeans(posterior_sims$beta)
      X(Intercept) XSpeciesversicolor  XSpeciesvirginica 
         5.0066682          0.9291718          1.5807763
```

**Confidence intervals**:

```
> # frequentist
> confint(fit)
                      2.5 %   97.5 %
(Intercept)       4.8621258 5.149874
Speciesversicolor 0.7265312 1.133469
Speciesvirginica  1.3785312 1.785469
> # Bayesian
> apply(posterior_sims$beta, 2, function(x) quantile(x, c(0.025, 0.975)))
      X(Intercept) XSpeciesversicolor XSpeciesvirginica
2.5%      4.862444          0.7249691          1.376319
97.5%     5.149735          1.1343101          1.783060
```